# Part of resized UIButton not responding to tap

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, rotation, uibutton, autolayout

So I added a UIButton into my UITableViewCell subclass and set Autolayout constraints to resize the UIButton when the tableview rotates. Everything goes well when the view is in portrait and the button responds to taps and fires the appropriate action method.

The problem is, the UIButton will stop responding to taps (partially!) when the tableview rotates into landscape view.

Here's some screenshots to better express the issue that I'm facing:

[image]
Portrait Orientation - Everything works as expected

[image]
Landscape Orientation - UIButton resized according to Autolayout constraints, but will only respond to taps within the red-boxed area. Any other taps outside the red-boxed area are ignored.

Comment: by other way, i recommend you using autosizing to do it and disable auto layout

Comment: @crz What's the advantage of doing that? This project uses Storyboard and I can't selectively disable Autolayout for this view controller alone.

Comment: by my experience, i am working on storyboard too and nerver use auto layout. I'm a man of old style right ^^, and you can disable auto layout in File inspector (in case you don't know how to disable it)

Comment: Has someone a solution?
I have exactly the same problem. After having modified NSLayoutAttributeHeight to help buttons have the size I need according to the device, half of the button is untouchable despite the fact that the button is correctly sized !